# Storing variants in array to create a 3 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an Excel table of point data that describes a tunnel. I am using a macro to import these points in a 3d modeling program (SolidWorks). Its very clear that there are 18 profiles that make up this tunnel. A task which I'm occasionally asked to do is to create a 3d model of data such as this. This involves me creating a closed spline for each of the 18 profile points and then lofting these closed spline to form a solid.

What I would like to do is to automate the creation of the splines by passing each set of profile points into a function that draws the splines. In order to do this I need to reorder the points so I don't get accidental crossovers.

A method that I am using is to find the angles between the points from the centroid of each profile.

In Excel, I first sort the points from minimum x value to maximum x value. I then use a For loop to run through the data set and a conditional statement to see if x_n+1 - x_n is below a tolerance value that I set. If the difference is below the tolerance, then Point_n+1 belongs in the set of previous points for the profile. In this conditional statement I am also taking a running sum. If the difference is greater than the tolerance, I calculate the centroid of the points for that profile.

The problem I am having is that in order to calculate the angle between the points with regards to the centroid point, I need to use the appropriate centroid value for each point set of the profiles. In my conditional statement I'm storing the x,y,z values in a variant called data. I need help storing data in an array so I can recall for later use which will create the splines. An example collection of points is included [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YEFpS0e-TTsF3sjVYENUv6Nvg78OFMna)

```
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim temp As Double
Dim yc As Double
Dim zc As Double
Dim temp2 As Variant
Dim xsum As Double
Dim ysum As Double
Dim zsum As Double
Dim a1 As Double
Dim a2 As Double
Dim data As Variant
Dim adiff As Double
Dim count As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

rownum = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
ReDim data(rownum, 3) As Variant


ysum = 0
zsum = 0

count = 0
For j = 1 To rownum - 1
    If j = 1 Then
        temp = 0
    Else
        temp = Abs(sh.Range("A" & j + 1).Value - sh.Range("A" & j).Value)
    End If

    If temp <= 2 Then
        data(j, 1) = sh.Range("A" & j).Value
        data(j, 2) = sh.Range("B" & j).Value
        data(j, 3) = sh.Range("C" & j).Value


        ysum = ysum + data(j, 2)
        zsum = zsum + data(j, 3)
        count = count + 1


        'Part.CreatePoint2 data(j, 1) / 1000, data(j, 2) / 1000, data(j, 3) / 1000
    ElseIf temp > 2 Then


        'calculate centroid
        yc = (ysum + sh.Range("B" & j).Value) / rownum
        zc = (zsum + sh.Range("C" & j).Value) / rownum


        'a1 = ATan2(data(j, 2) - yc, data(j, 3) - zc)
        'a2 = ATan2(data(j + 1, 2) - yc, data(j, 3) - zc)

        'adiff = a1 - a2


        ysum = 0
        zsum = 0

    End If

Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: So you just want help with syntax?
 https://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a better way to do this. Instead of using multiple For loops. If I continue with the way that I'm going, I'll have a For loop for storing the profile points in a new array, a For loop for calculating the angles, and after sorting the angles I'll have another For loop for actually drawing the splines.